# Full PDF view will not getting due to adding vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have created few forms and one pdf preview for this, whenever anyone will 
going to fill that form pdf preview will get updated with respect to it and after filling all the forms we can take pdf of it.

After i adding the vetical scrollbar to this pdf preview and going to take pdf by clicking on preview and download button i will not get full page pdf because of adding this vertical scrollbar.

please find the functionality at http://ibus.proserindustries.com/

I want to be kept this vertical scrollbar and also want to display full page on pdf how can we achieve it ?

Comment: Just remove that class '.ScrollStyle' which cases's scroll,In a function where you call open pdf form, Way of removing class differs for every pdf library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it helps to you just remove from style overflow x, y  and max height before the Popup

```
$('#printbutton').click(function() {
     $('.printable').css('overflow', 'auto');
     $('.printable').css('max-height', '100%');
     Popup($('.printable')[0].outerHTML);
     function Popup(data) {
         window.print();
         return true;
     }
});
```